# Gitlab pull mirror and diverging branches

Tags: gitlab

I have a repository I am setting up bidirectional mirroring for.

The interesting part here is the pull half.

1. I would like the default branch "develop" not to lose changes if the other side diverges.
2. I would like all other branches to do lose changes if the other side diverges.

Is it enough to switch Overwrite diverged branches on? Is there anything else we need to do?